# React Native component not rendering with async redux action in componentWillMount or componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a react native application created with CRNA. when calling an API for updated rates within componentDidMount or componentWillMount, the component no longer renders. I am using react-native-router-flux for routing. the actions are built to work with the redux-axios-middleware.

Component:

```
...
class CreateUser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { error };

  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getCountries();
}

onSubmit(data) {
  this.setState({error: error}); //clear out error messages

  this.props.createUser(data)
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <PageHeader
        title={'Create User'}
        subtitle={'Create a user under your default affiliate link.'}
        backButton />
      <Form fields={fields}
        showLabel={false}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        buttonTitle={"Create User"}
        error={this.state.error}/>
    </View>
  );
}

export default connect(null, { createUser, getCountries })(CreateUser);
```

Reducer:

```
...
case t.GET_COUNTRIES:
  return state;
case t.GET_COUNTRIES_SUCCESS:
  console.log(action.payload);
  return { ...state, countries: action.payload.data };
case t.GET_COUNTRIES_FAIL:
  return { ...state, error: 'Error Getting Countries' };
...
```

Action:

```
...
export function getCountries() {
  return {
    type: t.GET_COUNTRIES,
      payload: {
        request: {
        url: 'data/countries',
      },
    },
  };
};
...
```

When the component is routed to, the action runs and the payload is logged to the console, but then the component doesn't render. I am pretty new to React, should actions to dispatched elsewhere?

Comment: They don't render because you not rendering them anywhere. All you did is add `this.props.getCountries();` in componentdidmount which calls it but there is nothing in the view.

Answer (score 1):

They don't render because you not rendering them anywhere. All you did is add `this.props.getCountries();` in componentdidmount which calls it but there is nothing in the view.

You need to do something like this in your component.

`function mapStateToProps(state) { 
return { countries: state.theReducerName.countries} }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createUser, getCountries })(CreateUser);`

Then in your render you can use `<Text>this.props.countries</Text>`

Comment: They are being rendered in a child component. the component itself is not rendering. so the component before this one will stay rendered, but the console will log the result. I'm aware it isn't rendering countries, but it isn't rendering anything anymore.